# How to avoid/cancel application self run due to BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have application with BroadcastReceiver which listens to SD card mount/unmount, like:

```
public class ExternalDatabaseRemovingBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    private static final String TAG= ExternalDatabaseRemovingBroadcastReceiver.class.getName();

    public ExternalDatabaseRemovingBroadcastReceiver()
    {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if(Me.DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, "SD card mount/unmount broadcast=" + intent.getAction());
        if(intent.getAction()==null)
            return;
        if(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED.equalsIgnoreCase(intent.getAction()) ||
                Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_EJECT.equalsIgnoreCase(intent.getAction()) ||
                Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SHARED.equalsIgnoreCase(intent.getAction()))
        {
              //blah-blah
        }
    }
}
```

Broadcast is declared in AndroidManifest as:

```
<receiver android:enabled="true"
          android:exported="true"
          android:name=".ExternalDatabaseRemovingBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_SHARED"/>
        <data android:scheme="file"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And now my problem. During device launch (either real or emulator) - my application unintentionally runs. I mean ActivityManager self runs it reporting:

```
11-22 08:56:52.239: INFO/ActivityManager(61): Start proc ru.ivanovpv.cellbox.android for broadcast ru.ivanovpv.cellbox.android/.ExternalDatabaseRemovingBroadcastReceiver: pid=288 uid=10034 gids={1015}
```

Please explain what's goin on? And how to avoid application self running?

Comment: @Dr.nik ContentObserver doesn't related to this - it's another story!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that upon booting the device, the SD card is mounted as well, which triggers your intent filter. If you don't want this 'initial' mount to be registered by your app, you can perhaps ignore mounts that happen during the first x seconds of [uptime](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#uptimeMillis%28%29). That may not be the most elegant solution, though...

---

**Edit:** Now that I understand barmaley's original intent, the solution is much simpler. Intent-filters in the Android manifest are meant to start your application when something external happens. If you only want to react to (un)mounts while your application is already running, just register your broadcastreceiver programmatically in `Application.create` and unregister it in `Application.destroy` using `Context.registerReceiver` and `Context.unregisterReceiver` respectively.

Comment: LogCat reports that application runs before triggering Broadcast!

Comment: You mean your `Application` object is instantiated before your `ExternalDatabaseRemovingBroadcastReceiver` object? This is normal. Whichever entrypoint into your app is used, `Application` is created first.

Comment: Probably you're right, but I would be looking for more elegant solution. I'm not really happy when BroadcastReceiver triggers application to run, it's not really good.

Comment: What's wrong with your application running momentarily, as long as the user is not aware of it? You can only tell by looking at logcat. I don't think you can 'ignore' the initial `MEDIA_MOUNTED` broadcast. All you can do is look at it and terminate the application if the broadcast was irrelevant.

Comment: Maybe you can find out whether `BOOT_COMPLETED` or `MEDIA_MOUNTED` is broadcast first (I can't test right now). If `MEDIA_MOUNTED` goes first, you can ignore any mount that comes before `BOOT_COMPLETED` (by setting some internal flag). If `BOOT_COMPLETED` goes first, you can at least get a tighter bound on the time-period in which you ignore mounts. Of course, this does require your app to have the boot permission.

Comment: Also there's another concern against `uptimeMillis()` and `BOOT_COMPLETED`. Whenever user will mount/dismount SD card application will start again and again - it's unacceptable. I need to have another solution, right?

Comment: Wait... you don't **want** your application to be started when the SD card is manually (un)mounted? Then the solution is easy. Remove the intent filter from your android manifest entirely. Register your broadcastreceiver programmatically in `Application.create` and unregister it in `Application.destroy` using `Context.registerReceiver` and `Context.unregisterReceiver` respectively.

Comment: Thanx a lot - it's real solution

Answer (score 1):

It does sound like the system is responding to the SD card mounting at boot. You could whitelist access to starting this `BroadcastReceiver` by removing `android:exported="true"` or changing it to false, and enabling the use of `<permission>`. I don't know what your end goal of this is, so that may not be the best course of action.

Comment: I can't put `android:exported=false`, since I need to intercept media mount/unmount events - which are external